# how can I write a code when i click a button it have to go particular web site ...?

Tags: android, web-services, search

when i click a button it have to go one particular web site. i'm getting confusion how can write code on android please help me i did like this

xml code :

```
<Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="click me"
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:onClick="search"/>
```

java code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
        public void search(View view)
        {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write below codes to your onCreate method, after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Change google url with your url
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Also you should delete `android:onClick="search"` from your xml

Comment: thanks but i want to search with in my app only it asking on which browser u have open like that but i don't want like that when click on button it have to go with out asking browser

Comment: Then you should create an activity with a webview to open url in your application. Check this example. https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Comment: sorry its not working this it is working like intent

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very clear in your question -based on your comment to Batuhan's answer it sounds like you want to use a `WebView` - either way, you need to clarify what you want; 
Assuming you want a `Webview` - here is what you need to do:
Create a layout file that will load the Web page, call it my `web_page_viewer`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myWebPageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Then you create a "Web Page Viewing Activity" (I assume you wanted to use `Main2Activity`) where you will initialize and load the URL to be displayed:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //here you load your "Web Page Viewing" layout file
        setContentView(R.layout.web_page_viewer);
        //here you get handle to your WebView
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebPageView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //then specify the URL you want to load
        webView.loadUrl("http://ishlema.co.za");

    }
}
```

Then finally, your button click handler will now load the "Web Page Viewing" activity:

```
public void search(View view)
        {
         Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
```

I really hope this helps you. Please take some time and look at this complete and easy [Android WebView Example](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Comment: no its not working i download that code and imported then also it not working

Comment: You need to include the error log so we see what the problem is. The code should work - so perhaps there are things in your project that you did not mention which may inform our answers. Please include error log.

Comment: it working like intent nothing more then that while clicking on button it is goint to another button it continuesly moveing one activity to another

Comment: Please show us the code for `Main2Activity` - I want to see how it looks like;